# Assigning integers from a file to an array

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, while-loop

EDIT: Tried some suggestions and didn't alter too much but it kind of works gives me incorrect data but atleast they aren't zeros. Thanks everyone for thier assistance.

I'm writing code for reading grades from a text file and store them in an array. My full code is rather large so I'm only posting the part I having the issue in; my while loop not changing the values in the array. The sample data is 65 99 87 76 89 37 -999 all on separate lines. My output shows me that the array values remained zero after the function should have changed their values. The other while loops were all failed attempts at the same task.

```
int readGrades(double grades[]){
    FILE* gd;
    int count = 0;
    double ind;
    gd = fopen("sample.txt", "r");

    while(count < MAX){ //MAX is defined as 100/array is grades[MAX]
    fscanf(gd, "%lf", &ind); //Should scan through items in the file 
    if(ind < 0) //End of sample data is -999 this breaks out of the loop
        break;
    grades[count] = ind; //changes values in the array (it doesn't change them from 0)
    count++; } //increments the index of the array

   /*while(fscanf(gd, "%lf", &ind)>0){
    grades[count] = ind;
    count++; }*/

   /*do {
        fscanf(gd, "%lf", &grades[count]);
        printf("%.0lf", grades[count]);
        if(fscanf(gd, "%lf", &grades[count])== -999){
            break;
        }
        count++;
   }while(fscanf(gd, "%lf", &grades[count])> 0);*/
    fclose(gd);
    return count+1;
}
```

Some extra info: The grades array has to be initialized as double filled w/ 0s. I just need to replace the zeros in grades[] with the data from the text file.
I've been working on this for over a day now and still have had 0 progress. I just don't understand why it doesn't change the values in the array.

EDIT: This is where I call readGrades with the array data.

```
int numGrades;

numGrades = readGrades(grades);
```

right inside main. the #define MAX 100 and double grades[MAX] are delcared outside main. I return count+1 as the function needs to return the number of data items read.

Someone asked for the full program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int readGrades(double []);
void frequency(double [], int);
int maximum(double [], int);
int minimum(double [], int);
int deleteElement(double [], int, int);
double mean(double [], int);
double standardDeviation(double [], int);
#define MAX 100
double grades[MAX];
int loc;

int main(){
    int numGrades;
    printf("%lf", grades);
    numGrades = readGrades(grades);
    loc = minimum(grades, numGrades);
    numGrades = deleteElement(grades, numGrades, loc);
    printf("The data has been adjusted by removing the minimum %.2lf\n", grades[loc]);
    loc = maximum(grades, numGrades);
    numGrades = deleteElement(grades, numGrades, loc);
    printf("The data has been adjusted by removing the maximum %.2lf\n", grades[loc]);
    printf("The adjusted mean is %.2lf\n", mean(grades, numGrades));
    printf("The adjusted standard deviation is %.2lf\n",       standardDeviation(grades, numGrades));
    printf("Here is a histogram of the adjusted data:\n");
    frequency(grades, numGrades);
    return 0;
}
int readGrades(double grades[]){
    FILE* gd;
    int count = 0;
    double ind;
    gd = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
    while(count < MAX){
        fscanf(gd, "%lf", &ind);
    //double atod(ind);
        if(ind < 0)
           break;
    grades[count] = ind;
    count++;
}

/*while(fscanf(gd, "%lf", &ind)>0){
    grades[count] = ind;
    count++;
}*/
/*do {
        fscanf(gd, "%lf", &grades[count]);
        printf("%.0lf", grades[count]);
        if(fscanf(gd, "%lf", &grades[count])== -999){
            break;
        }
        count++;
}while(fscanf(gd, "%lf", &grades[count])> 0);*/
printf("%.0lf", grades[1]);
fclose(gd);
return count+1;
}
void frequency(double grades[], int numGrades){
    int j, i, a=0, b=a+4;
    for(j=0; j<numGrades-1; j++){
        printf("%d - %d|", a, b);
        for(i=0; i<numGrades; i++){
            if(grades[i]<=b && grades[i]>=a){
                printf("*");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    a+=5;
    if(a==100){
        break;
    }
}
printf("%d|", a);
for(j=0; j<numGrades; j++){
    if(grades[i]==100)
        printf("*");
}
printf("\n");
}

int maximum(double grades[], int numGrades){
    int i, h = 0;
    for(i=1; i<numGrades; i++){
    /*if(grades[i] == grades[h])
        continue;*/
    if(grades[i] > grades[h])
        h = i;
}
return h;
}

int minimum(double grades[], int numGrades){
    int i, h = 0;
    for(i=1; i<numGrades; i++){
    /*if(grades[i] == grades[h])
        continue;*/
    if(grades[i] < grades[h])
        h = i;
}
    return h;
}
int deleteElement(double grades[], int numGrades, int loc){
    int i;
    for(i=loc; i<numGrades-1; i++){
    grades[i] = grades[i+1];
    }
    return numGrades-=1;
}
double mean(double grades[], int numGrades){
    int i;
    double ans, sum;
    for(i = 0; i<numGrades; i++){
    sum += grades[i];
}
    ans = sum/numGrades;
    return ans;
}
double standardDeviation(double grades[], int numGrades){
    int i;
    double avg, sd, ans;
    avg = mean(grades, numGrades);
    for(i=0; i<numGrades; i++){
    sd += pow((avg - grades[i]), 2);
}
    ans = sqrt(sd/numGrades);
    return ans;
}
```

I appreciate you all helping me with this.

Comment: where are you trying to print values i.e. whether inside readGrades() function or from the caller function? Make sure you are accessing the same memory inside readGrades() function to fill the value which was declared in caller function.

Comment: I need to store the data from the file in the array. I'm not trying to print the values just use them.

Comment: That is what I meant; how do you see that your array has all zero values? You must be doing something like printf() to check that somewhere in your code. Where is that statement written?

Comment: It runs fine for me, so your error might be elsewhere.  Please post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem with the code you've posted, please show us how you access that data outside this function (I assume you're printing them somehow to see if it's working). Some thoughts: you should check if `fopen` was successful (otherwise you'll get a nice crash), and if the grades are integers, why are you using doubles?

Comment: What is the exact value  from MAX?

Comment: Why are you returning "count+1" ?

Comment: @Pottsy We can't diagnose your problem because we don't have enough code; show us how you call `readGrades` then how you check the contents of `grades`.

Comment: I edited the main post to where i call readGradesint numGrades;
 numGrades = readGrades(grades);

Comment: That's still not enough code.  We need to see a complete compilable program that exhibits the behavior in order to help you.

Comment: What value of `count` is being returned?  Are you sure you were able to open and read the file?

Comment: This is what I get running your code:
`
99The data has been adjusted by removing the minimum 0.00
The data has been adjusted by removing the maximum 87.00
The adjusted mean is 70.80
The adjusted standard deviation is 18.96
Here is a histogram of the adjusted data:
0 - 4|
5 - 4|
10 - 4|
15 - 4|
20|
`
so I think your code is OK so I don't know what's your issue

Answer (score 0):

Check the result of the `fopen` and `fscanf` calls:

```
gd = fopen( "sample.txt", "r" );
if ( !gd )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "error opening input file\n" );
  return 0;
}

while( count < max && fscanf( gd, "%lf", &ind ) == 1 )
{
  if ( ind < 0 )
    break;
  grades[count++] = ind;
}

if ( feof( gd ))
  fprintf( stderr, "hit end of file\n" );
else if ( ferror( gd ))
  fprintf( stderr, "error during read\n" );
```

Comment: I tried the top half nothing after the while loop and it says that there are errors opening the file. I don't understand how it doesn't open the file when called in the first line gd= fopen.... This only makes me think that my IDE or computer isn't recognizing the file.

Comment: @Pottsy: is your input file in the same directory as your executable?  If not, you will have to specify the file path (e.g, "/home/me/samples.txt" on Linux or "C:\\home\\me\\samples.txt" on Windows).  Are you sure the filename is correct?  Do you have permission to read the file?

Comment: I put the sample.txt int the same place as the .exe and it kind of worked wonky data but I can tweak with it.

Answer (score 0):

program is completely perfect. I am sure there is the issue in printf, the way you are using it. You paste the line where you are printing the values. I hope you must be doing something like this

```
printf("%lf\n",grades[i]);
```

Just for the betterment reason, you don't even need to pass grades[] as argument because that is global variable. FYI, in readGrades() it creates a local variable of the name grades[] when you are passing as reference.

Also, in readGrades() function "return count" should be ok as you're already doing increment of count within while-loop itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely OK as @Pawan said. this second line `printf("%lf"s, grades);` in the main is not needed and runs in a error (to me). If you have the sample.txt in the same "EXE" path wouldn't be any issue. If your sample.txt is in another folder you must reference it with full path.
this is the current output:

Printint values from loop:

65
99
87.000000
76.000000
89.000000
37.000000
99
The data has been adjusted by removing the minimum 0.00
The data has been adjusted by removing the maximum 87.00
The adjusted mean is 70.80
The adjusted standard deviation is 18.96
Here is a histogram of the adjusted data:
0 - 4|
5 - 4|
10 - 4|
15 - 4|
20|

if you cannot open the file try

```
if ( !gd ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "error opening input file\n", strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

to see the error. I think another process has opened the file.